# How to remove "prev, next, shortlink" from wp_head()?

Tags: theme-development

I'm using these filters to clean the head of my theme:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2);
remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3);
remove_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
remove_action('wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0);
remove_action('wp_head', 'locale_stylesheet');
remove_action('wp_head', 'noindex');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_styles');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts');
```

However, I can't seem to get rid of these:

```
<link rel='prev' title='Top Menu Item 1' href='http://localhost/test/test-prev.html' />
<link rel='next' title='Internal title test default title' href='http://localhost/test/text-next.html' />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://localhost/test/?p=528' />
```

Comment: Outside the scope of your question, but I wouldn't remove `wp_print_styles` or `wp_print_head_scripts`.  A lot of plugins are going to rely on those to enqueue styles and scripts.  Your theme will probably be enqueuing its own styles and scripts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One shouldn't remove them. They are important for search engines like Google.

One can remove them like this:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head');
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
```

---

Here are some additional explanations *why* they should not be removed and how this effects search engines:

- [Core Code insertion](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/18680)
- [The related trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18672)
- [Google Webmaster Central Article about changes & impact on SEO](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html)

In case one removes them, one should really add its own (in case one has changed their links and they are not pointing to the correct urls, that the pagination points to).

Comment: +1 for the link to pagination article from Google. However, WordPress puts pagination on the page regardless if the prev/next posts are related or not. WP should allow you to define a paginated series at the post/page level and only print the pagination links if that's present for the current page being viewed. This would meet the test and spirit of pagination as expressed in the google article and examples.

Comment: The trac ticket is talking about archives, not single posts, though Yoast suggests that the single implementation be changed to better reflect Google's stance. The next/prev would be important for archives and paginated articles, especially on sites that are extremely hard to crawl (eg. non-pretty permalinks). Finally, SEO is not about generalizations.  If you remove the links and see your index counts going down, then we can talk about the negative side effects of removing the links. But I suspect on a crawlable site, with good permalinks and internal linking, they won't make a difference.

Comment: +1 on both comments. Valid points. Anyway, I'd suggest to go with @ChristopherDavis comment: Don't remove them - watch their effect.

Answer (score 8):

Add these to your list:

```
<?php
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head');
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
```

`wp-includes/default-filters.php` should be your first stop to check out what WordPress is using its own hook system for.

Comment: There is a `;` missing from the second line.

Comment: true, but `default-filters.php` does nothing, the called functions are inside `link-template.php` and uses `wp_get_shortlink( 0, 'query' );` and function `wp_get_shortlink()` has a circuit filter, `'pre_get_shortlink'`, and finally return `apply_filters( 'get_shortlink', $shortlink` that serves the url.

Answer (score 5):

I've been struggling with this for a while, too, and it appears you should remove action with exactly the same parameters it was added.

so for me the following like in functions.php did the job:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10,0);
```

I'm using WP 3.3.1